# Showing an error message on form submit in angular2?

Tags: angular

I have implemented model driven form in [this demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HzZsf1DEbRTcwSyzyStu?p=preview). If the user doesn't enter anything and submits the form I am showing an error message using this logic

```
<div *ngIf="(!myForm.find('sku').valid && submitted)">**sku is required</div>
```

I am passing a boolean variable 'submitted' to check whether a control is valid or not when submitted. Is there any way to check the state of the control without passing a variable manually? Angular2 forms gives us 6 classes like `ng-touched`, `ng-untouched`, `ng-valid`, `ng-invalid`, `ng-pristine`, and `ng-dirty`. I want to show the error message using only these classes.

Comment: CSS is a markup and cannot be used for logic. You could write JS or TS to check for the presence of these classes on the elements, but this would be reinventing the wheel when the angular form controls are already doing that for you.

Comment: @SnareChops In angularjs there is a control like form.$submitted...is there anything like that in angular2?

Comment: In angular2 if the form is not valid it will never "Submit". So the form will never have a status of "submitted". There is a great guide [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) that goes very in depth into angular forms. I recommend reading the entire page, from top to bottom. It will explain how to do everything you are proposing.

Comment: Thank you i will read about it...

Comment: Setting `submitted` flag manually is okay.

Comment: @dfsq yea i have been doing manually but wanted to know is there any provision in angular

Answer (score 11):

I know that question is posted a long time ago, but I got the same problem and I wanted to utilize angular control states, so found this working properly:

First I would show error only if control is not pristine:

```
<span class="help-block" 
      *ngIf="request.get('control').hasError('required') && 
            !request.get('control').pristine">
      This field is required!
</span>
```

Then you can go trough all controls and mark them as dirty in onSubmit function:

```
onSubmit() {
//validations
this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
if (this.form.invalid) {
  Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(key => {
    this.form.get(key).markAsDirty();
  });
  return;
}

//call function for saving data
this.save(this.form.value);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: if (this.form.invalid) {
  Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(key => {
    this.form.get(key).markAsDirty();
    this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
  });
  return;
}

Comment: I like this solution better than manually setting a flag as that adds more complexity into your *ngIf regarding showing the error message before the user touched the form control.

Comment: BTW dirty is defined as !pristine `get dirty(): boolean { return !this.pristine; }` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/1b0b36d14322a77e67a106991174db36b1c8bcd7/packages/forms/src/model.ts

Answer (score 2):

Yes...

you can check ***`Angular form control's state`*** as show here.

**[Angular Form Control's Current State](https://plnkr.co/edit/Jqp6JRfNZRcQ4n04vLjM?p=preview)**

```
import {Component,View,bind} from 'angular2/core';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES,CORE_DIRECTIVES,FormBuilder, Validators } from 'angular2/common';
import {bootstrap}        from 'angular2/platform/browser';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app', 
  template: `
    <h1>LOGIN</h1>


        <form [ngFormModel]="loginForm"  #fm="ngForm"  (submit)="doLogin($event)">

        <input ngControl="name" type="text"  placeholder="Your name" #name="ngForm" required>

        <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">Name is required</div>

        <br/>

        <div>Valid ={{name.valid}}</div>
        <div>Pristine ={{name.pristine}}</div>
        <div>Touch ={{name.touched}}</div>

        <BR/><BR/>

        <input ngControl="password" type="password"  placeholder="Your password" #password="ngForm" required>

        <div [hidden]="password.valid || password.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">password is required</div>

        <br/>

        <div>Valid ={{password.valid}}</div>
        <div>Pristine ={{password.pristine}}</div>
        <div>Touch ={{password.touched}}</div>

        <BR/><BR/>

  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Log in</button>

</form>
    `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,FORM_DIRECTIVES,CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class Login { 
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.loginForm = fb.group({
      name: ["", Validators.required],
      password: ["", Validators.required]
    });
  }
  doLogin(event) {
    console.log(this.loginForm);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
 }
```

Don't forget to click the login button to check different objects associated with form in browser's console. Moreover I have tried to bind `valid-invalid strip` to the textbox which I used to implement in `Angular1`. I hope this will surely help you.

Comment: you have disabled the button until the form is valid...I want button to enable even if form is invalid and if user clicks on submit then i want to show the error messages

Comment: Oh I see ! Then look, it is necessary to pass the flag to check whether user has pressed submit button or not. If pressed, you set flag that true and use it with ngIf directive. And you have already done it. What else you want? Your sample is also correct.

Comment: yea my code works fine...Actually there is a flag like $Submitted in angularjs...wanted to know whether such provision is in angular2 also

Comment: As you do something with the textbox eg. touch,make it dirty, behind the scene angular2 makes changes in control's state and so that on immediate effect UI gets changed. So you get immediate effect. But if you want to do it with button's click event then you can access form control's property at TS/JS end and by some manual work you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would leverage the `pristine` and / or `touched` properties:

- If you want to display errors after the user fills something in a field, use the `pristine` property
- If you want to display errors after the user put the focus on a field, use the `touched` property

Here is a sample:

```
<div *ngIf="(!myForm.controls.sku.valid && !myForm.controls.sku.pristine)">
  **sku is required
</div>
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

I needed to show a validation banner at the top showing all of the form validation errors on submit and only on submit, which sounds like maybe what you were trying to do.

Currently running ng2 beta 17 and the framework does not prevent an invalid form from being submitted.  The browser will prevent html validation such as required from being submitted, but any other custom validators do not prevent the form submission.

My approach ended up being to have the validation summary banner handle the form submit with a callback to the parent on success.  If the form is invalid the banner shows the summary and does not callback.

**Form Setup**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="validationSummary.submit()" [ngFormModel]="myForm">
<div #validationSummary form-validation-summary [form]="myForm" [validSubmitCallback]="validSubmitCallback"></div>
...
<button type="submit" value="SaveButton" class="Button">Save</button>
</form>
```

**Page with form**

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    public validSubmitCallback: Function;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.validSubmitCallback = this.myFormSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    myFormSubmit() {
        alert("a valid form was submitted");
    }
}
```

**Validation Summary**

```
@Component({
    selector: '[form-validation-summary]'
    ...

export class FormValidationSummary {
    @Input() public form: ControlGroup;
    @Input() public validSubmitCallback: Function; 
    ...
    submit() {
        if (this.form.valid) {
            this.validSubmitCallback();
        } else {
            this.formSubmitted = true;
       }
    }
}
```

Related to adding submit on the form: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2960

Answer (score 0):

I have created the angular 2 version of ng-message.

The syntax is quite similar to ng-message:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" formControlName="phoneNumber" required>
    <cl-ng-messages [control]="formGroup.get('phoneNumber')">
      <template clNgMessage="required">
         This is required
      </template>
      <template clNgMessage="pattern">
        the format of phone number is not correct
      </template>
    </cl-ng-messages>
</form>
```

https://github.com/changLiuUNSW/ng-messages2